# oracle working with CTE with condition

Tags: oracle, cte

```
DEFINE fromtable1= true;
WITH firstQuery AS (
  SELECT columns FROM table
),
secondQuery AS (
  SELECT columns FROM second_table
)

  IF @fromtable1= true
  BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM   firstQuery 
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM   secondQuery 
  END
```

In oracle I tried above but I get error is there a way to make a query like this

Comment: `IF` is flow-control statement. It can be used in compound statement (procedure, function, trigger and so on) only.

Comment: @Akina is there a way where in I can select which table i would use to select after `CTE` ? any other way to do this kind of query?

Comment: Create stored procedure and usre your code in it.

Comment: @Akina you mean to say put the CTE in a stored procedure then use separately ?

Comment: In SP you do not need in CTE, in THEN you can execute only needed query immediately depends on which WHEN condition is true. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

As single query:

```
WITH firstQuery AS (
  SELECT columns FROM first_table
  WHERE @fromtable1
),
secondQuery AS (
  SELECT columns FROM second_table
  WHERE NOT @fromtable1
)

    SELECT *
    FROM firstQuery 
UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM secondQuery;
```

In stored procedure:

```
CASE WHEN @fromtable1
     THEN SELECT columns FROM first_table;
     ELSE SELECT columns FROM second_table;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted isn't Oracle so ... no wonder you got errors.

Maybe you don't even need to use CTEs, if `UNION` does the job. Note that this option requires that both `select` statements

- return the same number of columns (3 in this example)
- columns must match in datatype (in this example, it is a `number`, `varchar2`, `varchar2`)

This is SQL*Plus so I used substitution variable; depending on tool you use, you might switch to bind variable instead - in that case, just substitute `&&from_table` with `:from_table`.

```
SQL> SELECT empno, ename, job
  2    FROM emp
  3   WHERE     deptno = 10
  4         AND &&from_table = 1
  5  UNION ALL
  6  SELECT deptno, dname, loc
  7    FROM dept
  8   WHERE &&from_table = 2;
Enter value for from_table: 1

     EMPNO ENAME          JOB
---------- -------------- -------------
      7782 CLARK          MANAGER
      7839 KING           PRESIDENT
      7934 MILLER         CLERK

SQL>
```

---

If those two `select`s return **different** column set (not column names themselves, but different number of columns and different datatypes), then you can't do it in a single query (at least, as far as I can tell). In that case, one option would be to use function that returns ref cursor. For example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (par_from_table IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  IS
  4     rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5  BEGIN
  6     IF par_from_table = 1
  7     THEN
  8        OPEN rc FOR SELECT empno,
  9                           ename,
 10                           job,
 11                           sal,
 12                           hiredate
 13                      FROM emp
 14                     WHERE deptno = 10;
 15     ELSIF par_from_table = 2
 16     THEN
 17        OPEN rc FOR SELECT e.deptno, e.ename, d.dname
 18                      FROM emp e JOIN dept d ON d.deptno = e.deptno
 19                     WHERE e.deptno = 20;
 20     END IF;
 21
 22     RETURN rc;
 23  END;
 24  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT f_test (1) FROM DUAL;

F_TEST(1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL HIREDATE
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450 09.06.1981
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000 17.11.1981
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300 23.01.1982


SQL> SELECT f_test (2) FROM DUAL;

F_TEST(2)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO ENAME      DNAME
---------- ---------- --------------
        20 SMITH      RESEARCH
        20 JONES      RESEARCH
        20 SCOTT      RESEARCH
        20 ADAMS      RESEARCH
        20 FORD       RESEARCH


SQL>
```